# Using a flow, can you post in Chatter on behalf of another user

Tags: community, chatter, process-builder, visual-workflow

In our community, we want to post automated welcome messages in Chatter. Does anyone know if it is possible to use a flow and process builder to post to Chatter on behalf of another user, like say a community manager. I know that the ConnectApi does not allow this, but you can get around this in plain apex. I'm also curious if there is a declarative way around this as well.

Comment: If you can do it in plain Apex, you might want to think about an invocable that can be called from a flow.

Comment: Invocable is a good second option, thanks for mentioning. I'm still curious about doing this entirely declaratively.

Comment: Not sure if I have seen an option for a Process Builder to run as a specified user, it normally runs as a system user and flow runs as the calling user. Think this is worth trying to build a poc for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set `CreatedById` on `FeedItem` in visual workflow.

This will set who the post is from.

Couldnt figure out a way to do it in process builder, as the 'post to chatter' functionality doesnt let you set this, and 'feedItem' is not listed in the 'create a record' option

Screenshot of my assignment element and the test flow below

**Assignment element to construct feedItem sObject variable**

[image: assignment element]

**Flow**

[image: flow overview]

This flow successfully created a post on the ParentId user's feed, from the User set as CreatedById

[image: feedItem created]

Came across [another sfse post](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/102717/10062) that highlights one limitation of this approach - you can't at mention anyone or use topics.  Also not sure about any community specific considerations.

To at mention you need to use the standard [post to chatter element](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce_vpm_guide.meta/salesforce_vpm_guide/vpm_designer_elements_action_feed.htm), but it doesn't appear like you can set created by id going that route.

So if you need at mention capabilities along w created by id, a custom Apex plugin likely is needed.

Comment: The message body looks like something we'd all like to see.